# Nginx proxy_pass Rabbitmq Authorization

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq, authorization

Here is nginx config,
I want nginx to push request-data to the rabbitmq queue directly, but it doesn't work

nginx error log:

> 3208#9820: *130 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to
>   upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /post
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://[::1]:15672/api/exchanges/my_vhost/my_exchange/publish", host:
>   "localhost"

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /post {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/my_vhost/my_exchange/publish;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that RabbitMQ is running on localhost with that port and this is not a docker setup.

Comment: It works -->  http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/exchanges/my_vhost/my_exchange/publish

Comment: Works from where? Is Docker in play?

Comment: not running on docker

Comment: Well, it looks like you are sending an IPv6 request. Have you checked that RabbitMQ is set up to listen on IPv6 for that port? Or have you tried instead of localhost doing `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` for the `proxy_pass`

Comment: that also tried  -_-